# Configure or specify Marathonfile with Malinskiy's marathon gradle plugin?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I'm using the gradle plugin of [Marathon](https://malinskiy.github.io/marathon/doc/executing.html) to run my tests. Gradle tasks include "marathon" and "marathonInternalStagingAndroidTest". I can run both from Android Studio and the command line. What I can't seem to do, is configure it. The documentation doesn't say anything about configuring the gradle plugin.

Can it be configured through a gradle task? Or can it use a Marathonfile like the standard install uses?

./gradlew marathon -Pmarathonfile='/Users//Android/Marathonfile' runs the marathon task, but it doesn't use the Marathonfile I point to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of writing this, the gradle plugin does not utilize the Marathonfile. Also as of today, the [documentation](https://malinskiy.github.io/marathon/doc/configuration.html#gradle) has been updated! The config happens through adding groovy/kotlin DSL in your gradle file like this:

```
marathon {
    name = "sample-app tests"
    baseOutputDir = "./marathon"
    analytics {
        influx {
            url = "http://influx.svc.cluster.local:8086"
            user = "root"
            password = "root"
            dbName = "marathon"
        }
    }
    poolingStrategy {
        operatingSystem = true
    }
    shardingStrategy {
        countSharding {
            count = 5
        }
    }
    sortingStrategy {
        executionTime {
            percentile = 90.0
            executionTime = Instant.now().minus(3, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
        }
    }
    batchingStrategy {
        fixedSize {
            size = 10
        }
    }
    flakinessStrategy {
        probabilityBased {
            minSuccessRate = 0.8
            maxCount = 3
            timeLimit = Instant.now().minus(30, ChronoUnit.DAYS)
        }
    }
    retryStrategy {
        fixedQuota {
            totalAllowedRetryQuota = 200
            retryPerTestQuota = 3
        }
    }
    filteringConfiguration {
        whitelist {
            add(SimpleClassnameFilter(".*".toRegex()))
        }
        blacklist {
            add(SimpleClassnameFilter("$^".toRegex()))
        }
    }
    testClassRegexes = listOf("^((?!Abstract).)*Test$")
    includeSerialRegexes = emptyList()
    excludeSerialRegexes = emptyList()
    uncompletedTestRetryQuota = 100
    ignoreFailures = false
    isCodeCoverageEnabled = false
    fallbackToScreenshots = false
    testOutputTimeoutMillis = 30_000
    strictMode = false
    debug = true
    autoGrantPermission = true
}
```